# Delete and modify text in a bunch of files with python

Tags: python, file

I have a bunch of files called `test211.csh`, `test212.csh` and so on.  The first lines of each file I have:

```
"#$ -N /gridware/wor(number without 2)"

"#$ -o /gridware/wor(number without 2).out"

"#$ -e /gridware/wor(number without 2).err"

"#$ -cwd"
```

(without `""`)

For example `test238.csh`:

```
"#$ -N /gridware/wor38"

"#$ -o /gridware/wor38.out"

"#$ -e /gridware/wor38.err"

"#$ -cwd"
```

I want only in the same file:

```
"#$ -N (name of the file without CSH)"
```

Also I want to replace `"//"` with `"/"`

How can I do that?

Comment: you could just extract the first few characters you know till reaching the first /

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you're suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
from glob import glob
from itertools import islice
path = "full_path/"
import ntpath

for f in glob(path + "*.csv"): # find all .csh files 
    with open(os.path.join(path, f)) as fl:
        data = fl.readlines()
    with open(os.path.join(path, f), "w") as w:
        # write filename - .csh
        w.write("#$ -N {}\n".format(ntpath.basename(f).rstrip(".csh")))
        for line in data[4:]:
            # write remaining lines
            w.write(line.replace("//", "/"))
```

Comment: Does this change the first lines? I want to replace "//" with "/" as well change "#$ -N /gridware/wor(number without 2)"
"#$ -o /gridware/wor(number without 2).out"
"#$ -e /gridware/wor(number without 2).err"
"#$ -cwd"
to "#$ -N (name of the file without CSH)"

Comment: @AndréMonteiro, this will rename the files removing the .csh, your code already replaces the `//`.  Do you want to rename the files or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to do? I don't see csh anywhere in the files only in the filename itself

Comment: No I don't want to rename the file... maybe I will try to post my question with my code so far

Comment: @AndréMonteiro, I am not sure where CSH is coming from. adding exactly the output you want from the input you provided will help

Comment: csh is the extension of the file. I want to remove the first block of 4 lines and turn that into the one I have put in the question

Comment: @AndréMonteiro, just strip the .csh and write from line 5-end

Comment: something is still missing... It prints everything I want except that in the line #$ -N test(number) prints the whole path instead #$ -N /pathto/test(number)